# iptables DNAT original destination

Tags: routing, nat, linux

I'd like to write a proxy software to manipulate incoming and outgoing packets from/to a specific device. For incoming packets, it is easy: Add a PREROUTING iptables entry for packets going to the device's IP and route them to another IP:Port. There I can modify the packets and forward them to the real destination (my device).

But what do I do with outgoing packets? When I try the following

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp -s 10.0.0.10 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.20:13000` (with 10.0.0.10 being the device I want to monitor and 10.0.0.20 my computer which monitors)

then I'll get all the packets send by the client, but I have no clue about their real destination because the destination IP in the IP header gets rewritten ...

Answer (score 1):

The translation information used by linux nat is available in /proc/net/ip_conntrack

Alternatively rather than mess arround with nat you might want to look into the queue target in iptables along with libipq. This will let you mess with the packets in userland without having to mess around with NAT.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/libipq

Answer (score 0):

NAT on a stateful firewall only needs one rule to match the initial connection, and takes care of the return packets.

The only requirement is that the device that receives the final packet after the dNAT, must route the return traffic back through the stateful firewall to allow it to do the reverse NAT.

If the FW is your GW it is normally not a problem, if it is not, you could add a masquerade on the FW to also hide the src (after it changed the destination) thus forcing your PC to respond back to the FW.

Comment: But how does the firewall know it's a "return packet"? Lets say 172.16.1.2 sends a packet to 10.0.0.10 and my firewall rewrites that to 10.0.0.20:13000. Then, a proxy software rewrites the contents and sends the packet - with a spoofed source address of 172.16.1.2 - to 10.0.0.10. When the device now answers on that packet, how will the firewall know to forward that outgoing packet to my proxy software, too, and, more important, how is my proxy software supposed to find out the real destination?

Comment: @Florian Bach,  run  "$ sudo conntrack -L"  this will show you where the connections are being tracked.